# How to position divs inline with same spacing

Tags: html, css

I've the following divs in my document:

```
<div class="bill-header">
    <div class="bill-header-info"><span>Bill No</span></div>
    <div class="vline"></div>
    <div class="bill-header-info"><span>Table No</span></div>
    <div class="vline"></div>
    <div class="bill-header-info"><span>Room No</span></div>
    <div class="vline"></div>
    <div class="bill-header-info"><span>Amount</span></div>
</div>
```

I'm using the following CSS to make them sit on one line:

```
.bill-header {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.bill-header-info {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 3px;
}

.vline {
    width: 2px;
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
```

How can I make them appear with same distance in between them?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IMESH/3Zv2y/)

Comment: Your explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv2y/2/

Make these changes:

```
.bill-header-info {
    width:23%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 5px` in your .vline:

```
.vline {
    width: 2px;
    height: 80%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
    border-left: 1px solid gray;
    margin:0 5px;
}
```

This will give a margin of 5px in both left and right of your vline element.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9h3s/)

Answer (score 0):

use width property in css for exapmle

```
 .bill-header-info {width:22%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Zv2y/1/)

As long as there are always four items in a row, you can use a "fixed" percentage value:

```
.bill-header {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.bill-header-info {
    float: left;
    width: 24.6%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

The important parts are the `width` and `text-align` properties in `.bill-header-info`

Answer (score 0):

```
.bill-header-info {
text-align:center;
width:23%;
float: left;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-right: 3px;
```

}

```
.vline {
width: 2px;
height: 80%;
display: block;
float: left;
margin-top:3px;
margin: 0 5 3 3px;
border-left: 1px solid gray;
```

}